# How to create the perfect array using Push in array (woocommerce re-create cart)

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I'm looking to create an array that would look like this

```
$cart = array([product_id] array([size], [quantity]));
```

Here is the info I'm having on my page :

```
86253//35//1
86253//36//1
86253//38//2
86253//39//3
86253//40//2
86245//36//7
86245//39//4

$product_id // $size // $quantity
```

and here is how I get it :

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
      $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
        if($_product->post_type == 'product_variation'){ 
            echo $_product->parent_id; echo '//'; echo $values['variation']['taille'];  
            echo '//'; echo $values['quantity'];
        }                  
    }
```

how can I create my perfect array using push_array php function ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
// the array to store the data
$cart = array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) 
{ 
   $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());

   if($_product->post_type == 'product_variation')
   { 
       echo $_product->parent_id; echo '//'; echo $values['variation']['taille'];  
       echo '//'; echo $values['quantity'];

       // create the new temporary array to save the data structure 
       $tmp = array( $_product->parent_id, array( $values['variation']['taille'], $values['quantity'] )  );

       // add the tmp array to the storage array
       array_push($cart, $tmp  );
   }                  
}
```

If you print out the "cart" array it will look this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 86253
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 35
                [1] => 1
            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 86253
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 36
                [1] => 1
            )

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 86253
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 38
                [1] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

**EDIT:**

That's not exactly what you wanted but it should also group the array data by the product id:

```
// the array to store the data
$cart = array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) 
{ 
    $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());

    if($_product->post_type == 'product_variation')
    { 
        echo $_product->parent_id; echo '//'; echo $values['variation']['taille'];  
        echo '//'; echo $values['quantity'];

        // Check if the parent_id is already set as array key
        if( !array_key_exists ( $_product->parent_id, $cart ) )
        {   
            // use the parent_id as key 
            $cart[$_product->parent_id]  = array();     
        }

        // create the new temporary array 
        $tmp = array( $values['variation']['taille'], $values['quantity'] );

        // add the tmp array to the $cart
        array_push($cart[$_product->parent_id], $tmp  );
    }   

}
```

If you print it out it should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [86253] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 35
                [1] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 36
                [1] => 1
            )

    )

    [86245] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 36
                [1] => 7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 39
                [1] => 4
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's almost what I want... but is there a way to group by product ID ? 
The array  would be :
array(
[0] => 86253
[1] => array ([0] => 35 [1] => 1)
[2] => array ([0] => 36 [1] => 1)
)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!